# ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size) is not creating backing byte[] in Android 2.2 emulator

Tags: java, android, bytebuffer

I'm new to android.  I can't seem to find pertinent forum posts.

What has me stumped is that `allocateDirect()` **does** create the backing byte[] in Android **4.2** emulator.

More specifically, I allocate a ByteBuffer, and call `buffer.put(byte[])` several times to write the contents of the ByteBuffer.  I then want to hand off the backing byte[] for compression.  It's accessing the backing byte[] that throws the UnsupportedOperationException.

Here's the resulting buffer contents just after writing when running the Android 2.2 emulator:

[image]

Here's the resulting buffer contents just after writing when running the Android 4.2 emulator:

[image]

The difference seems to be in whether `bufferRef.block` is created (it's created when the ByteBuffer is allocated in the Android 4.2 emulator).  I would prefer to always use a direct ByteBuffer.  As a workaround, I check to see whether I have access to the backing byte[], and if not, re-allocate using `ByteBuffer.allocate(size)`.

```
        ByteBuffer buf;
        try {
            buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.maxBufferSize);
            if(!buf.hasArray()) { //some API levels either don't expose or create the backing byte[]  
                buf = null;
                buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(this.maxBufferSize);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
```

So, my question is, is there a way to guarantee a direct byte buffer will always have a backing byte[] (assuming enough memory)?  Or do I have to live with this workaround?

Environment:

ADT Build: v21.0.0-519525

Android 2.2 emulator config:

Updated AVD 'AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google' based on Android 2.2, ARM (armeabi) processor,
[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.sdCard=no

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.device.manufacturer=Google

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.mainKeys=no

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=320

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.accelerometer=yes

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.dPad=no

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.device.hash=-708107041

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.trackBall=no

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.device.name=Galaxy Nexus

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.back=none

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.proximity=yes

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.battery=yes

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] disk.dataPartition.size=200M

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.audioInput=yes

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.orientation=yes

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.front=none

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.gps=yes

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] skin.dynamic=no

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.keyboard=yes

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=64

[2012-12-20 10:09:34 - SDK Manager] hw.ramSize=512

Comment: Having a backing `byte[]` and being a direct byte buffer are, usually, diametrically opposed things.  If a `ByteBuffer` is truly "direct," it will not have an array; otherwise, it will.

Comment: @LouisWasserman "A view buffer is potentially much more efficient because it will be direct if, and only if, its backing byte buffer is direct."  So, you are saying a direct backing byte buffer is not a byte[].  I tested that theory by checking buf.isDirect().  The backing buffer is direct in the Android 4.2 environment.  Regardless, I guess the question is really how can I access the direct byte buffer at any API level?

Comment: I don't think I follow.  Checking `buf.isDirect()` and checking `buf.hasArray()` are different things.  But all that said, if you want to "access the direct byte buffer at any API level," why not...use the `ByteBuffer` methods other than the `array()` and `hasArray()` methods?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Strange: `buf.slice()` returns a DirectByteArray with a direct buffer with the same OS address as the original.  I presume this means no copying has taken place.  The important thing is, when I act on the DirectByteArray returned by `buf.slice()` there's no exception thrown...growing pains.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no byte buffer for Android 2.2.  The buffer is optional.  It was implemented in later releases.

Answer (score 1):

A better answer is `.allocateDirect()` does not create a backing array. You must call `ByteBuffer.get(byte[])` to populate an array from the given buffer.

Comment: ByteBuffer.java line 202:   final byte[] hb;            // Non-null only for heap buffers